# UV map of ripped model won't show up

Tags: uv, import

Today, I've started with ripping some models of Yooka-Laylee.

With the tool 'Unity Studio' I've got the obj files out of Unity's resource files. I've imported the .obj file (a barrel) into blender and wanted to see if everything works fine. The model showed up as it should and everything seemed working. But when I wanted to see the model with textures, the model was just completly white. After I opened the UV-Editor, I realised that the UV map just isn't there.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? I've been searching on the internet for about 30 minutes but I haven't found an answer.

[image]

Comment: Personally I've always had problems with OBJ, as far I can see Unity Studio can export to FBX format, try that one.

Comment: The problem is that Unity Studio exports the FBX files in the ASCII format which isn't readable for blender. And if I try to convert it into a binary FBX file, the file is just empty.